# Trying to set a TextView's font to bold from within the onBindViewholder class (my adapter for a Recyclerview)

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, textview

I have a value stored in SharedPreferences for a current match name. I am also displaying a bunch of names in a recyclerview. I have created an onClickListener on each listItem in the recyclerview. How can I change the text of the listItem's (Textview's) font to bold if it matches the value stored in sharedPreferences?

Currently I'm attempting this from the onBindViewHolder method. I may be approaching this all wrong. Initially I tried to set it in the viewHolder's class but I wasn't doing something right. Here is my code:

```
package com.checkinsystems.ez_score.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.checkinsystems.ez_score.EditMatchActivity;
import com.checkinsystems.ez_score.MatchActivity;
import com.checkinsystems.ez_score.R;
import com.checkinsystems.ez_score.model.Match;

import java.util.List;

import static com.checkinsystems.ez_score.MainActivity.CURRENT_MATCH_ID;
import static com.checkinsystems.ez_score.MainActivity.CURRENT_MATCH_NAME;
import static com.checkinsystems.ez_score.MainActivity.MY_GLOBAL_PREFS;


public class MatchItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Match> mMatches;
    private final Context mContext;

    public MatchItemAdapter(Context context, List<Match> items) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMatches = items;
    }

    @Override
    public MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_match, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Match match = mMatches.get(position);

        try {
            holder.tvName.setText(match.getMatchName());
            holder.tvDate.setText(match.getMatchDate());
            holder.imageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.hiddenMatchId.setText(match.getMatchId());

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, 0);
            if (sharedPreferences.toString().equals(holder.tvName.getText().toString())){
                holder.tvName.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMatches.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDate;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView hiddenMatchId;
        public View container;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_name);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_date);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            hiddenMatchId = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_id_hidden);
            container = (View)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_container);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), imageView);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.edit_match:
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), EditMatchActivity.class);
                                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                    break;
                                case R.id.delete_match:


                                    // to delete a match here

                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    //displaying the popup
                    popup.show();
                }
            });

            container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences
                            (MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, itemView.getContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, tvName.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH_ID, hiddenMatchId.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), MatchActivity.class);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, 0);
    if (sharedPreferences.toString().equals(holder.tvName.getText().toString())){
        ...
    }
```

To this:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentMatch = sharedPreferences.getString(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, null);
    if (currentMatch != null && currentMatch.equals(holder.tvName.getText().toString())) {
        ...
    }
```

Why make these changes? If you look at the code where you're writing data to the shared preferences, you'll see this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences
                        (MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, itemView.getContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, tvName.getText().toString());
editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH_ID, hiddenMatchId.getText().toString());
editor.apply();
```

The name of your preferences store is `MY_GLOBAL_PREFS`, so you need to use this to retrieve the store later on. You're storing string values using `CURRENT_MATCH_NAME` and `CURRENT_MATCH_ID`, so you need to use these keys to retrieve those string values from the store.

Note that you'll also need to add an `else` clause to your `if` to set the typeface back to non-bold if the values don't match. This is because of the recycling behavior of `RecyclerView`. If you don't set the typeface to non-bold when the values don't match, any time the `RecyclerView` re-uses a `ViewHolder` that previously had a match, your text will be bold.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get the desired result by posting this in the onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Match match = mMatches.get(position);

        try {
            holder.tvName.setText(match.getMatchName());
            holder.tvDate.setText(match.getMatchDate());
            holder.imageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.hiddenMatchId.setText(match.getMatchId());

            Typeface bold = Typeface.create("san-serif", Typeface.BOLD);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                    MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String currentMatchName = sharedPreferences.getString(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, "current_match_name");
            String itemName = holder.tvName.getText().toString();

            if(itemName.equals(currentMatchName)){
                holder.tvName.setTypeface(bold);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should add an `else` to set the typeface to non-bold in the non-match cases (or else view recycling will give you bold text where you don't want it).